# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange Delegate not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am having trouble with a new view I have created, I have a registration view that has a single UITextField on it and a UIButton.

I call this view from another view like so

**//otherview.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RegistrationAlertViewController *regreg = [[RegistrationAlertViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:regreg.view];

}
```

Then I create my regregview like this

**//regregView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RegistrationAlertViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {


    // textfields for registration
    IBOutlet UITextField *registrationTextFieldA;


}

// textfields for registration
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *registrationTextFieldA;

@end
```

**//regregView.m**

```
#import "RegistrationAlertViewController.h"

@interface RegistrationAlertViewController ()

@end

@implementation RegistrationAlertViewController

@synthesize registrationTextFieldA;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    registrationTextFieldA = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    registrationTextFieldA.delegate = self;

    [registrationTextFieldA becomeFirstResponder];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField.text length] > 4)
    {
        //Get next TextField... A simple way to do this:
//        UITextField *newTextField = [textField.superview viewWithTag:(textField.tag+1)];
//        [newTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
        //remember to set the tags in order
    }
    return YES; //you probably want to review this...
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if((textField.text.length + string.length) > 4)
    {
        //Get next TextField... A simple way to do this:
//        UITextField *newTextField = [textField.superview viewWithTag:(textField.tag+1)];
//        [newTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        //remember to set the tags in order
    }
    return YES; //you probably want to review this...
}


@end
```

I have the two delegates in my regregView.m

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing
- shouldChangeCharactersInRange

for some bizarre reason **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** is entered when the view first loads but then when I start entering characters into **registrationTextFieldA**  **shouldChangeCharactersInRange** is never being entered for some bizarre reason.

any help figuring out why my delegates are not working properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have declared the textfield as IBOutlet in property but you are allocating it by yourself. If textfield is not coming from XIB file then remove the IBOutlet property.

Comment: Have you attached delegate of UITextField ?

Comment: @HurkNburkS have a try

Comment: okay I Have completely restarted the view to get rid of any code that might be breaking things.. and still I am reciving this EXC BAD ACCESS when editing UITextField... its driving me nuts I am still looking for a solution I will let you know how I get onl

Comment: Turns out, Im not sure why but when I declared everything in my ViewController that was being added as a subview to mainView the delegatemethods dont work. However when i just add everything to mainView the delegate methods then work.... I am not sure how to fix this problem. anyone got any ideas? :P

Answer (score 1):

Include UITextFielDelegate category in yourClass.h file and Try this code .

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    int length = textField.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    if(length > 4)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField.text length] > 4)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES; //you probably want to review this...
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allocate `UITextField` instance in `viewDidLoad` method. Replace you code with this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    registrationTextFieldA.delegate = self;
    [registrationTextFieldA becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess here.
The problem is in your otherview.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     RegistrationAlertViewController *regreg = [[RegistrationAlertViewController alloc] init];
     [self.view addSubview:regreg.view];
}
```

Try making a strong property of RegistrationAlertViewController on top of your otherview.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RegistrationAlertViewController *regreg;
```

Then in your view did load, you can do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     RegistrationAlertViewController *regreg = self.regreg;
     if (regreg == nil)  
    {
        self.regreg = [[RegistrationAlertViewController alloc] init];
    }

     [self.view addSubview:regreg.view];

}
```

Hope that works.. Just seems like a similar problem I ran into before.. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add UItextField delegate from your xib outlet and declare delegate protocol `<uitextfielddelegate>` in your .h file.

Definitely it will work fine for You.

Good Luck !!!!

Answer (score 0):

**As you are initializing the view while implementing this file.So set delegate in init method not in viewDidLoad.**

```
@synthesize registrationTextFieldA;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    registrationTextFieldA = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    registrationTextFieldA.delegate = self;
    [registrationTextFieldA becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```